# Every time I change the redirect address on one site it changes another

Tags: iis-7.5

I've got 2 websites, both need to redirect to different addresses. Every time I click on the site and click HTTP redirect from the right hand pane it changes the other site redirect. They are both running on the same application pool but I don't think that this should really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Both sites were pointing to the same physical folder so updates to the web config were affecting both sites.